# Get data from NSMutableArray & pass data to DetailView in story board

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uistoryboardsegue

I have a plist file like this

```
<array>

    <array>

        <dict>

            <key>name</key>

            <string>Ryan</string>

            <key>image</key>

            <string>088i.png</string>

            <key>webSiteURL</key>

            <string>http://www.ryan.com</string>

            <key>category</key>

            <string>Monday</string>

        </dict>

    </array>

    <array>

        <dict>


            <key>name</key>

            <string>Pinky</string>
            <key>image</key>

            <string>089i.png</string>

            <key>webSiteURL</key>

            <string>http://www.pinky.com</string>

            <key>category</key>

            <string>Sunday</string>


        </dict>

        <dict>


            <key>name</key>

            <string>Kitty</string>

            <key>image</key>

            <string>098i.png</string>

            <key>webSiteURL</key>

            <string>http://www.kitty.com</string>

            <key>category</key>

            <string>Sunday</string>


        </dict>

    </array>

</array>
```

This plist will be load to a NSTableView as a NSMutableArray, Now I want to pass data to DetailView, how to get specific data actually?

I use

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TableToWebSegue"]) {
        NormalDetailView *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.webSiteURL = [[_cellContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"webSiteURL"]
    } }
```

But it said indexPath is wrong and should be NSIndexPath, I change it to NSIndexPath but it said .row is wrong...

This is my first app, I have no idea how to get data in this case, if I want get webSiteURL, how to do it? How to pass it to detail view?

Comment: Where does `indexPath` come from?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to get data in a TableView...

Comment: You get the data as usual - set up a data source, put the data into its items, and finally display the controller with a table referencing the newly created data source.

Comment: I successfully display it in a tableView, but I need pass the data of the cell when it is pressed. For example, the data "webSiteURL" will pass to detailView and use it to open a WebView. How can I pass data when a cell is pressed? I'm a new guy in programming, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your prepareForSegue method is in the UITableViewController that is you master controller, then just add this line to your prepareForSegue method:

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

Then, you can use indexPath.row like you have it in your post.

After Edit: In response to your comments, I took a look at your project, and the error is occurring on lis line in NormalViewController:

```
detailViewController.name = [[_cellContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

The problem is, that [_cellContentList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is a NormalCategory object which doesn't have an objectForKey: method. It has a normalList property, which in itself has 2 normalData objects, which in turn have a "name" property. I assume it's that name property you're trying to get to, but which one? Since there are 2 normalData objects, you have to have a way to pick which one you want. It seems to me that your data structure is overly complex and confusing (at least to me).

Comment: thx! it shows no error. But when I run the App, actually press the cell, it crash and show "-[NormalCategory objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7292960", what does it mean?

Comment: @RyanTsang, it means that NormalCategory (whatever that is) doesn't understand objectForKey:. Is NormalCategory a class or an instance? And what kind of an object or class is it?

Comment: It is a class, the function is load data by category from plist. like this:

Comment: ＠implementation NormalCategory
＠synthesize category = _category;
＠synthesize normalList = _normalList;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)normalList {
    
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary *item in normalList) {
            NormalData *data = [[NormalData alloc]initWithItem:item];
            [list addObject:data];
        }
        
        NormalData *data = [list objectAtIndex:0];
        _category = data.category;
        _normalList = list;
    }
    return self;
}

＠end

Comment: I don't know how to say it, this is a simple sample, can you take a quick look for me? thank you~ https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29588413/Dragon%20Roar%20s.zip

Comment: I don't understand the data structure actually, so I can't see there are 2 normalData objects, can you explain it more detail? sorry I'm just a stater in programming.

Comment: What do you mean, you don't understand the data structure? It's your code. Did you not write it?

Comment: I tried use below code in "- (void)prepareForSegue", but it pass the first cell data to detailView whatever which cell is selected:         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NormalCategory *category = [_cellContentList objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        NormalData *data = [category.normalList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        detailViewController.name = data.name;
        detailViewController.webSiteURL = data.webSiteURL;

Comment: I haven't figured it all out yet, but the immediate problem is that indexPath is NULL, so it's picking section 0 row 0 all the time.

Comment: The data structure part is come from a sample in internet, I use it to get data from plist and show in tableView.

Comment: @RyanTsang, the reason the indexPath is null, is because touching the detail disclosure indicator doesn't select the row. If you select the row first, and then click the detail disclosure indicator, then it works correctly.

Comment: In the original sample, it use a method in NormalDataCell class to open the URL in the cell by Safari, is it possible to do something in this class to pass data correctly? The original code is: - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (selected) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_webSite];
        
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url]){
            NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Failed to open url:",[url description]);
        }
    }
}